# Cannot start APC or Memcached modules with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, memcached, apc

I've compiled PHP 5.3.9 and NGINX 1.0.11 and want to use APC and Memcached with PHP. I keep getting this error when attempting to load the APC/Memcached modules:

Unknown(0) : Warning - PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,debug
These options need to match

I tried recompiling (configure, make, make install) PHP without the --enable-debug option, but still no luck. Any ideas on what I need to do to get these options to match?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to avoid this error by compiling an new version of PHP (5.3.10) without the "--enable-debug" option.